# How to do comparison (less than) like Excel do for column in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I use typescript and I index some data the way Excel does. I mean A, B, C, ... Z, AA, AB, ...

Now I would like to do some comparisons, like this:

```
var X1 = "A";
var X2 = "C"
var X3 = "AB"

if (X1 < X2) {
    //...
}

if (X2 < X3) {
    //...
}
```

But comparing X2 (=C) < X3(=AB) returns false because comparison in letter by letter.

How to do comparison (Excel-like) for returning (column) "C" < "AB" ?

Comment: Maybe you could first test for length (assuming longer text is always > shorter text) like `X2.length < X3.length && X2 < X3`. Although in general it seems like an ugly way for comparing to me, I just dislike using math operators on strings directly. You could just calculate all individual letters asci values, multiply/pow(val, pos) and compare that.

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe something like ...

```js
function compare(a, b) {
  a = a.split('');
  b = b.split('');
  return a.some((e, i) => b[i] && a < b[i]);
}

var X2 = "C"
var X3 = "AB"
console.log(compare(X2, X3));
console.log(compare(X3, X2));
```

Comment: While your solution works for X2="C" ; X3="AB"; it does not work for other tests like X2="A" ; X3="AB";

Answer (score 0):

You can sum each character ASCII code and compare the total :

```js
function sum(str) {
  return str.split('').reduce((acc, it) => acc + it.charCodeAt(), 0);
}

function compare(a, b) {
  return sum(a) - sum(b);
}

console.log('A lower than C', compare('A', 'C') < 0);
console.log('C lower than AB', compare('C', 'AB') < 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can already compare strings and that almost works for your case but in your case if the length is smaller then the string is lower rank no matter the letters. You can do it like this:

```js
String.prototype.lessThan = function(rhs) {
  return this.length < rhs.length || (this < rhs);
}

var X1 = "A";
var X2 = "C"
var X3 = "AB"

console.log( X1.lessThan(X2) );
console.log( X2.lessThan(X3) );
console.log( `AB` .lessThan `A` );
console.log( `AB` .lessThan `BC` );
```

You can name the function something more appropriate if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have (partially thanks to Gabriel Bleu)

```
String.prototype.lessThan = function (arg: string): boolean {
    // For comparing index like Excel columns
    // A, B, C, ... AA, AB, AC, ...
    var aa = this.split('');
    var bb = arg.split('');
    if (aa.length < bb.length) return true;
    if (aa.length > bb.length) return false;
    return aa.some((e, i) => bb[i] && aa[i] < bb[i]);
}
```